# how can I print HTML element with it's original style?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angular

I am trying to print HTML element using `window.print();`
but the html is viewed without the original style. how can I fix it?

```js
printInvoice() {
    var mywindow = window.open("", "PRINT");

    mywindow.document.write("<html>");
    mywindow.document.write("<body>");
    mywindow.document.write($("#html2pdf")[0].outerHTML);
    mywindow.document.write("</body></html>");

    mywindow.document.close();
    mywindow.focus();

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();

    return true;
  }
```

css:

```css
@media print {
  #invoice {
    padding: 30px;
  }

  .invoice {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    min-height: 680px;
    padding: 15px;
  }

  .invoice header {
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #3989c6;
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried following the steps in this article? https://www.sitepoint.com/css-printer-friendly-pages/

Comment: you are opening a blank new page/tab. You should also write the css there

Comment: Also why not `document.getElementById("html2pdf").outerHTML` now you are using DOM anyway

Comment: Thanks @BrunoGois this article is very helpful, unfortunately it doesn't include a working example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rendering happens based on html, css, and js. This is why you need all these three in your new page.

Assuming that Your css and js is only in the head, you can do the following

```
printInvoice() {
    var mywindow = window.open("", "PRINT");

    mywindow.document.head.append(document.head)
    mywindow.document.body.innerHTML = $("#html2pdf")[0].outerHTML;
    mywindow.focus();
    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();

    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing, it works, but now after closing the popup, the main page is corrupted, i fixed it, and will share the solution in the next comment.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you guys for helping, following is what worked for me:

```
 printInvoice() {
    var mywindow = window.open("", "PRINT");

    mywindow.document.write("<html>");

    mywindow.document.write(document.head.outerHTML);
    mywindow.document.write("<body>");
    mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById("html2pdf").outerHTML);
    mywindow.document.write("</body></html>");

    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();

    return true;
  }
```

in your css file, style you print page using

```css
@media print {...}
```